# How to connect SCSS to HTML?

Tags: html, sass

The part of the code which does not work:

```
<link href="rStyle.scss" rel="stylesheet/scss" type="text/css">
```

I have also tried using simple CSS command, still nothing. I just
started so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't use Sass directly, it has to be compiled. Are you using VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

You should compile the scss first if you use a text editor like `vscode` that is available plugins called `live-sass-compiler.`
You need to install that and click the `watch sass.` Please read the plugin documentation if you didn't understand.

Comment: It says "working on it" for 15 min still nothing

Comment: That little bit strange, did output show something?

Comment: Nope it did not show anything :(

Comment: You can use the method from the documentation of Sass.
1. Install sass cli : [Install Sass](https://sass-lang.com/install)
2. Run this command `sass --watch app/sass:public/stylesheets`